# applicationMusicPlayer stops when user locks the screen on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, locking, ipod

I set the audio session category to kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback, I active the session, which returns no errors, and still the iPod music stops when I lock the device. This happens on iOS 5 GM, so I guess this will happen in the final version. On iOS 4+ the current code works fine. Any ideas how to fix this? Huge thanks :)

Comment: iOS 5 is still covered by an NDA so most people with knowledge of this won't answer in public. You might like to try to the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Good point :) Thank you!

Comment: Having similar problem, issue posted here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/561581#561581 I think this is a bug in iOS 5.

Comment: Actually, I think this is a bug in XCode 4.2. I compiled the exactly same code with XCode 4.1, and it works fine on a device, even it's running iOS 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. To save power locking the phone is now treated as if the user pressed the home button. The fact that `applicationMusicPlayer` stops now when locking is just a side effect of this change.

To work around this problem you should switch to AVPlayer and make use iOS 4's audio in background mode.

Comment: Thank you, voidStern! I tried using AVPlayer, but it still mutes when the device is locked. I understand why iOS 5 sends the app to background mode, but I think they should respect the audio session category being set to media playback and at least continue to play sounds... Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you set the background audio category in your info.plist? If you've done everything right it should continue to play even if you exit the app via your home button. (If you don't want that you'll have to stop the playback in your App Delegate)

Comment: I did, and it still stops. But in my case the problem is that the sounds stops when the screen is locked, it's ok for the sound to stop when the home button is pressed.

Comment: ...but since iOS5 locking the screen and pressing the home button is literally the same things as far as your apps is concerned.

Comment: yup, unfortunately... The only solutions I've found so far are not good: 1. Compile with XCode < 4.2, but that means I won't be able to use any of the new iOS 5 features. 2. Mark the app as not running in the background, but this is even worse in my case...

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue for my particular problem - how to detect the difference between OS4 and OS5 behavior when device gets to the Lock screen.

In OS4 app does 'applicationWillResignActive' but on OS5 it goes all the way to 'applicationDidEnterBackground' which looks exactly the same as the user hitting the Home button.

It turns out that if you check the UIApplicationState of the application given in '- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application', it has 3 possible values:

```
typedef enum {
   UIApplicationStateActive,
   UIApplicationStateInactive,
   UIApplicationStateBackground
} UIApplicationState;
```

When the user hits home on OS5, you get UIApplicationStateBackground, but when the user hits Lock, you get UIApplicationStateInactive.

Hope that helps.

Happy Holidays everyone.